# Is "angry towards someone" correct?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

We can say, angry with/ at someone. Is angry towards someone correct? For example, I'm very angry with my friend, Mara. Can I say: I'm very angry towards Mara?

Comment: It's possible,but I don't know the difference in meaning.

Comment: In "I'm very angry towards Mara?" you are saying that your anger is going in the direction of Mara. It is not wrong, but certainly a more passive construction than saying "I'm very angry with my friend, Mara".

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say it is *wrong*, but it sounds odd.  If you want to indicate a direction for your anger, "at" sounds more natural:

> I am very angry **at** Mara.